# Is it possible to create an APP with a total budget of 100 USD?

Tags: dapps, dapp-development, dapptools

I want to create a decentralized application either in Ethereum, solana, avalanche, etc.
networks, this application allows you to link your files to blockchain tokens, the problem is that I hear: creating an application based on a smart contract will not be cheap to implement.

**So, does it make sense to create a business model based on a smart contract in 2022, or is it better to create a traditional application?**

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of an arbitrary question, because Dapps can vary in size. That being said, if the budget of $100 is only needed for gas fees, then you will likely have no problem affording a deployment on a L2 like polygon or avalanche. You won't have a problem on a more centralized L1 like Solana or TRON. Depending on the gas fees at the time, you may even be able to deploy on Ethereum, but that's typically a much more expensive pathway.

Comment: Awesome, thank you very much, I thought that it is impossible to create a smart contract because I only see the Ethereum L1 gas fee, which of course is absolutely expensive.